# How to reduce the overhead of emitting an event from DPI?

Tags: specman, e

I’m using e coverage for sampling signals in my DUT.
In order to sample the covergroup, I’m emitting the coverage sample event inside a DPI code (defined in c interface of e, called in my hdl code).
But it seems like when emitting this event there is a lot of overhead which is not related to the coverage collection.
What can I do in-order to reduce this overhead?

Answer (score 1):

Try to define, emit and handle all coverage groups and event in e. 
That way you'll not get the overhead of transition between languages.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of emitting the event, use the API for procedural sampling of the event (covers.sample_cg())
For example if you have a covergroup named cg1, defined in a type t1, and you’d like to sample it for t1_inst of t1, then instead of calling :

```
emit t1_inst.cg;
```

call :

```
covers.sample_cg(“t1.cg1”, t1_inst);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define event(s) that is more relevant to the needed signals. 
You can also define event on specific bits of a bus change.